# Is there any way to make the April Fools gravity modifier stay past April Fools?

Tags: dying-light

Is there any way to make the April Fools gravity modifier stay past April Fools? Now that I've nearly completed the game, and have mostly higher level gear, I'd like more time to, "experiment" with the zombies and have a little more fun with the modified physics.

Comment: Does changing your system clock to April 1st work?

Comment: Doesn't seem like that's working for me :C. I totally forgot about playing Dying Light last night and now it's a huge bummer just seeing all these gameplay videos of kicking zombies halfway across the map.

Comment: It'll be a download that gave you that ability.  The devs will most likely just release a new patch taking it away.  The only way to stop it would be to have an Offline mode version of Steam on a PC with the game, including the Aprils fool prank, and never let Steam connect to the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Techland (the game's developer) applied the April fool's modifier as a patch which basically puts the modifier firmly in their control. It's their patch and they're able to apply or revoke it at their privilege.

There isn't an in-game setting to enable or disable the event. Disconnecting your console or PC from the internet on April 1st also doesn't work (I've tried).

However, if you're playing on PC you can install [this Nexus Mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/dyinglight/mods/103/) which replicates some of the April fool's features such as high-power drop kicks and reduced fall damage. It also applies some more extreme changes such as making weapons unbreakable and applying infinite ammunition. For the time being this is the closest you'll be able to recreate the event outside of April.